# How to modify the “asc" "desc" schema in jQuery's legacy Datatable sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a table that with one column of strings, but my strings are in the following format: A1, A2, A12, A100, A200, A20.

Right now when I click on the sorting button in the table header, my data are sorted as: A1, A100, A12, A2, A20, A200; how I want my data to be sorted is: A1, A2, A12, A20, A100, A200.

I am thinking that I can first sort my data by length of the string, and then use the traditional sorting algorithm for strings (I assume the original 'asc' 'desc' should do the work), but I don't know where I should go about this.

Where should I go to change the 'asc''desc' algorithm? Or is there any other ways to sort the data?

Thank you!

Comment: This is covered in the [sorting documentation](https://datatables.net/development/sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [natural sorting](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural) plug-in.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columns: [
      { type: 'natural' }
   ]
});
```

Please note that you need to include additional JS file.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbf9wyjf/1/) for code and demonstration.